# Keycloak-js client forward custom param

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak, idp

I am using the keycloak-js library in an Angular project and needs to forward the acr_values param when logging in, so that my idp knows which login method to use.

The forwarding inside keycloak is working, but I don't know how to forward the param from the login function.

Comment: I would try to use `createLoginUrl()`

Comment: I did fix it by modifying the createLoginUrl() function.

Comment: It will be nice to contribute back to community and providing answer with the code snippet, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add the following snippet in keycloak.js under kc.createLoginUrl

```js
if (options && options.acr_values) {
   url += '&acr_values=' + encodeURIComponent(options.acr_values);
}
```

Then it can be used as

```
keycloak.login({
   redirectUrl: XXXX,
   acr_values: XXXX
})
```